# Turn off case sensitivity in SolrNet fields

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am facing a problem with the case sensitivity of SolrNet Filters. e.g. new SolrQueryByField("City", "Chicago") returns the results but SolrQueryByField("City", "chicago") does not return anything because "chicago" is in lower case.

I am not sure how to turn case sensitivity off for filters. I don't want any of my fields to be case sensitive, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Field `City` is probably unanalyzed (i.e. of type `solr.StrField`). Make sure it uses a `TextField` with `LowerCaseFilterFactory`. See for example `text_general` in the [sample Solr schema](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/example/solr/conf/schema.xml?view=markup). After changing your schema you'll have to rebuild your index.

Comment: Thanks Mauricio, you have been awesome!